# Search a multi-dimensional array for certain values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array in the following format:

```
[0] = (
    'id' => '1',
    'type' => 'fish', 
    'owner' => 'bob',
)

[1] = (
    'id' => '2',
    'type' => 'cat', 
    'owner' => 'mary',
)

[2] = (
    'id' => '3',
    'type' => 'dog', 
    'owner' => 'larry',
)

[3] = (
    'id' => '2',
    'type' => 'cat', 
    'owner' => 'fred',
)
```

I would like to search for a value, and they return an array that contains all keys from matching arrays and looks like this on a search for type=cat:

```
[0] = (
    'id' => '2',
    'type' => 'cat', 
    'owner' => 'mary',
)

[1] = (
    'id' => '2',
    'type' => 'cat', 
    'owner' => 'fred',
)
```

I know I'm trying to treat the array as a database, but in this case it's dynamic data that doesn't need to be stored once the program ends.

Any advice?

Comment: remember select an accepted answer if you found one.

Comment: @Neal, don't worry, I'm going to. Just testing it first. It's a large array so it takes a while to run, plus I'm good with typos.

Comment: i noticed :-P i fixed them in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop through the array:

```
function loopAndFind($array, $index, $search){
         $returnArray = array();
         foreach($array as $k=>$v){
               if($v[$index] == $search){   
                    $returnArray[] = $v;
               }
         }
         return $returnArray;
}

//use it:
$newArray = loopAndFind($oldArray, 'type', 'cat');
```

Comment: @Drazisil, no problem ^_^ anytime

Answer (score -2):

you must iterate array like:

```
foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
    print "$i {\n";
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        print "    $key => $value\n";
    }
    print "}\n";
}
```

and then check for 'type' key value....
then record which is matched must copy it to new array...

Comment: I just have traversed as  you did in your reply, and have written description that he should save match result in new array...that is what you have show it through code.