# Search records with in an two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search-engine

i am trying to do one thig ,but i am not getting the point.can anyone please suggests me ..
two dimensional array like below

```
$array = Array
([1] => Array
    ([1] => EST_ID
     [2] => EST_CODE
     [3] => EST_EXT
     [4] => EST_NAME
     [5] => INCROP_ADDRESS1
     [6] => INCROP_ADDRESS2
     [7] => INCROP_CITY
     [8] => INCROP_DIST
     [9] => INCROP_STATE
     [10] => INCROP_PIN
     )
 [2] => Array
    ([1] => HRKNL0006923000
     [2] => 6923
     [4] => VAIBHAV CARPETS
     [5] => BHUL-BHULIA CHOWK
     [6] => BODHWA RAM COLONY
     [7] => PANIPAT
     [8] => PANIPAT
     [10] => 132103)

 [3] => Array
    ([1] => HRKNL0004638000
     [2] => 4638
     [4] => GURU TEG BHADUR PUBLIC SCHOOL
     [5] => MODEL TOWN
     [6] => KARNAL
     [7] => KARNAL
     [8] => KARNAL
     [10] => 132001)
)
```

i have to search the array key of either 2 or 3 from $array

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, Amar Ranjan Das. Could you clarify what result you expect from your search?

Comment: Please remember to mark an answer if one solved you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure which one you need as I didn't fully understand the question but one of these two functions will help [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to do what I asked in [Search a multi-dimensional array for certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494907/search-a-multi-dimensional-array-for-certain-values)