# Checking for date string in multidimensional array and returning corresponding keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in the following format:

```
$array = array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-25',
      'name' => 'Bob'
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-25',
      'name' => 'Brian'
    ),
  2 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-26',
      'name' => 'Jack'
    ),
  3 => 
    array (
      'date' => '2013-03-26',
      'name' => 'Bob'
    )
);
```

I have a PHP loop which cycles through each date of the year (this works fine).  Within this loop I would like to check if there are any entries in the array above for the date in question, and if so, for each entry found return the corresponding key for 'name'.  I want to run a SQL query for each name returned, so presumably I would create another loop for these queries.

I have tried a few things but only succeeded in getting into a muddle.  Perhaps there is a relatively straightforward way of achieving this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: @JohnConde I don't have any helpful code to show.  I have tried using an array_key_exists() function, and the function used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494907/search-a-multi-dimensional-array-for-certain-values), amongst others, without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array2 = array();
foreach( $array as $item )
    $array2[$item['date']][] = $item['name'];
```

now to check whether there are names for some date, you just check

```
if( isset( $array2[$date] ) )
# do something
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have tried using it and it is returning all of the dates found in the array, rather than the names found for each of the dates.  I'm not sure if I am missing something here.  Could you explain the steps a little more?

Comment: what do you do to use it? $array2['2013-03-25'] should be array('Bob','Brian')

Comment: Thanks, I have this working now.  Instead of using `if( isset( $array2[$date] ) )`  I am using `foreach($array2[$date] as $name)` and then running a query for each name.  I now have a third key in the array called 'time'.  How would I check the 'time' key within the foreach loop?